# How to define a NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to add NSArray with NSString values in it. I'm almost sure that I can use `#define` for it, but I don't understand how to access and initialize that declared variables.
For example i have:

```
#define my_definition 0;
```

And i know how to access this 0 value. But how about NSString inside NSArray?

I have a definitions.h file. In there i have access from any my class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoa... what are you trying to do here?

`#define` is a preprocessor macro.  The preprocessor knows nothing about Objective-C (or C for that matter... it's just a glorified text replacement engine), and Objective-C knows nothing about the preprocessor.

You almost certainly don't want a `#define` for anything other than *maybe* numeric values (e.g. `int`s) or an `NSString`.  (In practice, you will usually see `extern NSString * ...` in lieu of `#define` for a variety of reasons, too.)

If you need access to a particular `NSArray` in an object, you can create an ivar that you populate in `-init` or the like.  If other classes need access to the array, make it a `@property` or just declare a (public) method.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: No, thanks for that! That's explain a lot, and i'm look at my problem in a wrong way at beginning.

Answer (score 4):

If you use #define, you define a preprocessor macro. It's NOT a global variable. Instead where ever you use that macro it will be replaced by what's after #define and only then will your code be compiled.

That being said, you can simply define an NSArray just as you would somewhere else:

```
#define kMyArray [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MyString1", @"MyString2", nil]
```

Notice, that I didn't end the line with a semicolon. Imagine if I now wrote somewhere in my code:

```
NSString *str1 = [kMyArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will be replaced by:

```
NSString *str1 = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MyString1", @"MyString2", nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

If I had a semicolon in my definition, I would get a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

I came across someone else's code a few months ago that I adapted to my own purposes, mainly to save myself a lot of typing.  I apologize in advance to the original author, I would love to give credit where it is due but I dug through my hard drive and couldn't find either the original samples or his or her name.  If I do come across the original source I'll amend this post with the name of the original author.

At any rate, the basic idea is to use a $ character as your macro prefix character and then take variadic arguments.  Yes, both gcc and Apple's LLVM compiler support this.  I've gone absolutely crazy and converted nearly all the core types (arrays, strings, dates, dictionaries, etc.) based on a few examples, but here are some ideas to get you going:

```
#define $string( _format, _args... )        ( [NSString stringWithFormat: ( _format ), _args] )
#define $stringUTF8( _format, _args... )    ( [[NSString stringWithFormat: ( _format ), _args] UTF8String] )

// shorthand container creation (NSArray, NSMutableArray)
#define $array( _objs... )                  ( { id objs[] = { _objs }; [NSArray arrayWithObjects: objs count: sizeof(objs) / sizeof(id)]; } )
#define $arrayM( _objs... )             ( { id objs[] = { _objs }; [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: objs count: sizeof(objs) / sizeof(id)]; } )
```

This lets you do some neat things like the following:

```
NSArray *           array;

array = $array( @"foo", @"bar", $string( @"This is a %@ string", @"formatted" ) );
```

Saves a *whole* lot of typing!

Comment: FYI, this answer is really old. Use the array-literal syntax in Objective-C that was developed after I posted this, e.g. `NSArray *array = @[@"foo", @"bar", @"baz"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MY_DEFINITION @[ @"String1", @"String2" ]
```

Preferably without the semicolon

Comment: I believe that requires the new collection literals that are not available yet for use in production releases of Xcode.

Comment: @Tom or Conrad: Where did you read about collection literals?  I've been bugging Apple about this for ages and they replied that it was a fairly common request.  This should have been built into the language long ago but as you can see from my post above it is possible to roll your own (not nearly as elegantly as a language-feature, but still doable).

Comment: @par It was unveiled under NDA in the Mountain Lion developer preview but was subsequently made public at llvm.org (IIRC) in the fresh compiler builds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm looking forward to checking it out.

Comment: These are definitely a step in the right direction but I was hoping to also see some syntax for releasable objects as well.  I think I'll continue to stick with the macros I've been using for a while since it's really just shorthand and the objects I create can be (auto)released.

Comment: @par I'm not quite clear on what you mean by "releasable." In any event, with the advent of ARC, you don't have to think much about the implementation details, save for method naming and interfacing with Core Foundation.

Comment: Doh.  I got thinking about @true and how it would be a nice optimization to have just one of those resident for the application lifetime.  From there I started thinking about compiler-generated string tables and somehow wandered into "these are all persistent objects" territory.  Of course there's no reason why they couldn't or wouldn't be subject to ARC+GC like any other object.  Unfortunately now I'm *am* really interested in the implementation details. :)